# Error loading MySQLdb module. Did you install mysqlclient? on MacOS

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

Am Trying to connect to my mysql db from django app.
I get the below error during migration:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb
>   module. Did you install mysqlclient?

I've already installed mysqlclient as below:

> Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.2.post1)

I've also tried with pymysql and adding below code to **ini**.py file:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Gives me some other errors.
What could be wrong?

Python 3.7 , mysql 5.7 and Django 2.2 are my setup versions.

Comment: Are you using the same environment for running django as you installed the MySQL client in?

Comment: What do you mean? Everything is on localhost

Comment: you need to check any virtual environment installed or not for your project. activate it and try to migrate. for activation in linux:- source envname/bin/activate

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Yes i've also tried through virtualenv and i get the same error

Comment: check with pip freeze

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Output is: Django==2.2.3
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.17
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
protobuf==3.9.1
PyMySQL==0.9.3
pytz==2019.1
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
virtualenv==16.7.2

Comment: can you post your masked db settings

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. Running the below command fixed it for me.

`pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --no-binary :all: mysqlclient`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The thing that worked for me is the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54521244/12497648,

except when I did `brew install mysql-client` 
I got the message `Warning: mysql-client 5.7.23_1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 5.7.23_1, run "brew reinstall mysql-client"` so I ran `brew reinstall mysql-client` after which I continued with the instructions from the link above (export PATH... etc.)

(also don't forget to do the `pip wheel mysqlclient` / `pip install mysqlclient`)

Answer (score 0):

If the error includes a `Reason: image not found` error, then it can be solved with symlinks like this:

[Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib Reason: image not found Django migrate error using mysqlclient DB driver and MySQL 8 with macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590645/library-not-loaded-rpath-libmysqlclient-21-dylib-reason-image-not-found-djang)